# Crashlytics don't report 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)' crash

Tags: cordova, crashlytics

I have a `cordova` project app with `crashlytics` integrated and it reports correctly the crashes but there is a case that never reports, when the application crashes on background.

From the `logcat` I get this:

> 12-29 13:33:23.214   167   167 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1
> (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 2bc01020 12-29 13:33:23.224   878   878 E
> ImagerControl: TransferI2C mIOControlFunction Failed retry 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     r0 00000001  r1 00000000  r2
> 2bc01020  r3 63a19004 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> r4 61aadbd4  r5 00000003  r6 0000000f  r7 61aadbcc 12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     r8 63a189bc  r9 61aadd10  sl 61aadcb0  fp
> 61aadcbc 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     ip 00000000
> sp 61aadbb0  lr 00000000  pc 62a21a08  cpsr 600f0030 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d0  0000000000000000  d1
> 0000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d2
> 0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167
> I DEBUG   :     d4  3a74656720202020  d5  6f6974636e756620 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d6  6572207b2029286e  d7
> 696874206e727574 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d8
> 0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167
> I DEBUG   :     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13
> 0000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d14
> 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167
> I DEBUG   :     d16 656c6c6f72746e6f  d17 2933342863632e72 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d18 6f7078650a3b7465  d19
> 535043542e737472 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d20
> 636f537265767265  d21 4354203d2074656b 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167
> I DEBUG   :     d22 5372657672655350  d23 650a3b74656b636f 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d24 3f5224a519195837  d25
> bf5224a1000bf7dc 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d26
> 402b148710c79339  d27 4000000000000000 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167
> I DEBUG   :     d28 400061e92c09fa6f  d29 3fa7b80000000041 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31
> 412e847ffffffffc 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     scr
> 80000012 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   : backtrace: 12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     #00  pc 00652a08
> /data/data/com.zestdataservices.ocf.retailer.reg/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.314   167
> 167 I DEBUG   : stack: 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb70  648fbae0   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb74  648fcea8   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb78  648fcf00   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb7c  648fbae0   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb80  648fbae0   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb84  648fcf08   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb88  648fbae4   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb8c  400e13a7  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50) 12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadb90  648fce10   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadb94  648fbae4   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadb98  648fbae0   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadb9c  648fce18   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadba0  648fbae4   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadba4  400e13a7  /system/lib/libc.so
> (dlfree+50) 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadba8  648fbad0   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbac  00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
>
> ## 00  61aadbb0  61aadbf4  [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbb4  00000003   12-29 13:33:23.314   167
>
> 167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbb8  61aadc16  [stack:28272] 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbbc  61aadc14
> [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbc0  61aadc04  [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I
> DEBUG   :          61aadbc4  62a21d67
> /data/data/com.zestdataservices.ocf.retailer.reg/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbc8  6465d730
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbcc  648fba88
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbd0  619292f8
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbd4  400e13a7
> /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50) 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :          61aadbd8  61aadc14  [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167
> 167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbdc  61aadc04  [stack:28272] 12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :          61aadbe0  61aadc0c
> [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbe4  6465d730   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbe8  61aadc14  [stack:28272] 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I
> DEBUG   :          61aadbec  62a17a75
> /data/data/com.zestdataservices.ocf.retailer.reg/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.314   167
> 167 I DEBUG   : memory near r2: 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     2bc01000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01010 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 2bc01020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01040 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     2bc01050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01060 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 2bc01070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc01090 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     2bc010a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc010b0 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 2bc010c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc010d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     2bc010e0 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     2bc010f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I
> DEBUG   : memory near r3: 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a18fe4 00000000 0000000e 00000010 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18ff4 00000000 00000000 0000000f 00000010
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19004 2bc01020
> 00000000 00000000 00000010   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a19014 00010004 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19024 00000012 0000000b
> 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a19034 00000000 00000014 0000000f 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19044 00000000 00000000 00000016 0000000c
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19054 2bc01040
> 00000000 00000000 00000018   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a19064 0000000c 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19074 0000001a 0000000f
> 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a19084 00000000 0000001c 00000007 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.314
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a19094 00000000 00000000 0000001e 0000000f
> 12-29 13:33:23.314   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a190a4 2c001ce0
> 00000000 00000000 00000020   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a190b4 00030004 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a190c4 00000024 00000004
> 2bc010e0 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a190d4 00000000 00000028 0000000f 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near r4: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbb4 00000003 61aadc16 61aadc14 61aadc04   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbc4 62a21d67 6465d730 648fba88 619292f8
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbd4 400e13a7
> 61aadc14 61aadc04 61aadc0c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadbe4 6465d730 61aadc14 62a17a75 61aadc04   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbf4 61aadc16 641ff368
> 62589eab 64957ec0   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc04 00000000 6256bcad 638ddd60 00000003   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc14 00610006 00700070 00000000 6271d62b
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc24 6104cf08
> 639f5b1c 634a88a1 65ed8fa8   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc34 619292f8 61aadd10 634aa101 0000411a   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc44 00000000 00000003
> 6394bcd8 61aadcc4   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc54 be931734 61aadc78 400ddca9 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc64 63555278 61aadccc 6104d0d4 65ece858
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc74 64905740
> 00000021 625efad9 0000001c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc84 00000001 65ece858 00000000 65dc9a10   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc94 6256ad01 61aadccc
> 61aadccc 6104d0d4   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadca4 6104d0ec 61aadcc4 6394bcd8 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near r7: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbac 00000000 61aadbf4 00000003 61aadc16   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbbc 61aadc14 61aadc04 62a21d67 6465d730
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbcc 648fba88
> 619292f8 400e13a7 61aadc14   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadbdc 61aadc04 61aadc0c 6465d730 61aadc14   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbec 62a17a75 61aadc04
> 61aadc16 641ff368   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbfc 62589eab 64957ec0 00000000 6256bcad   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc0c 638ddd60 00000003 00610006 00700070
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc1c 00000000
> 6271d62b 6104cf08 639f5b1c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc2c 634a88a1 65ed8fa8 619292f8 61aadd10   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc3c 634aa101 0000411a
> 00000000 00000003   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc4c 6394bcd8 61aadcc4 be931734 61aadc78   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc5c 400ddca9 00000000 63555278 61aadccc
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc6c 6104d0d4
> 65ece858 64905740 00000021   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc7c 625efad9 0000001c 00000001 65ece858   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc8c 00000000 65dc9a10
> 6256ad01 61aadccc   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc9c 61aadccc 6104d0d4 6104d0ec 61aadcc4   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near r8: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a1899c 00000004 63a17520 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a189ac 000003fc 00000004 00000001 62cc5541
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a189bc 00a49000
> 00c00000 004e0000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a189cc 00000000 00000000 2c800000 2c754000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a189dc 2c7fc000 2bc01000
> 2bc01000 6ce01080   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a189ec 2bc012c0 2bc012e0 2bc01720 2c201d00   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a189fc 2c201da0 2c201e20 2c201d20 2bc01e20
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18a0c 2be010e0
> 2c0019c0 2bc01800 2be01500   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a18a1c 2be01280 2be01460 2c001b20 2bc01ea0   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18a2c 0000000e 9c5e7643
> 00000001 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a18a3c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18a4c 00000001 00000002 00000003 00000004
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18a5c 00000005
> 00000006 00000007 00000008   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     63a18a6c 00000009 0000000a 0000000b 0000000c   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     63a18a7c 0000000d 0000000e
> 0000000f 00000010   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 63a18a8c 00000011 00000012 00000013 00000014   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near r9: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadcf0 00000021 00000011 65dc9a10 6342bc00   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd00 64a135c8 00000000 00000000 00000000
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd10 00000021
> 00000011 645fefb8 40119e00   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd20 64a135c8 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd30 00000000 61aadd6c
> 6104cf08 6195ee5c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd40 00000000 625b3aa7 619b0000 be931734   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd50 4011c2ec 634ab1b3 61aadd6c 6195ee5c
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd60 61aadd6c
> 634ab1db 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd70 6195ee28 6195ee30 61aadd84 625b5b8b   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd80 625b3aa7 5fe10a48
> 0000001b 6abfd550   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd90 687ab860 640e7af8 6195ee28 6438b138   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadda0 687ab860 625b3ae3 61aaddd0 640e7af8
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aaddb0 625b3aa7
> 400dd224 687ab860 640e7af8   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aaddc0 61aaddd0 0000000b 00000078 400dd3bc   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aaddd0 61aaddd0 640e7af8
> 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadde0 00000000 45b743ec 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near sl: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc90 65dc9a10 6256ad01 61aadccc 61aadccc   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadca0 6104d0d4 6104d0ec 61aadcc4 6394bcd8
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcb0 00000000
> be931734 61aadccc 65e87888   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadcc0 61aadccc 64905740 65ee0f01 6104cf08   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcd0 00000000 6104d088
> 61aadd6c 6394bcd8   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadce0 61aadd10 be931734 6104cf0c 634ab16b   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcf0 00000021 00000011 65dc9a10 6342bc00
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd00 64a135c8
> 00000000 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd10 00000021 00000011 645fefb8 40119e00   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd20 64a135c8 00000000
> 00000000 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd30 00000000 61aadd6c 6104cf08 6195ee5c   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd40 00000000 625b3aa7 619b0000 be931734
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd50 4011c2ec
> 634ab1b3 61aadd6c 6195ee5c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd60 61aadd6c 634ab1db 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd70 6195ee28 6195ee30
> 61aadd84 625b5b8b   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd80 625b3aa7 5fe10a48 0000001b 6abfd550   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near fp: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc9c 61aadccc 6104d0d4 6104d0ec 61aadcc4   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcac 6394bcd8 00000000 be931734 61aadccc
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcbc 65e87888
> 61aadccc 64905740 65ee0f01   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadccc 6104cf08 00000000 6104d088 61aadd6c   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcdc 6394bcd8 61aadd10
> be931734 6104cf0c   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadcec 634ab16b 00000021 00000011 65dc9a10   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadcfc 6342bc00 64a135c8 00000000 00000000
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd0c 00000000
> 00000021 00000011 645fefb8   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd1c 40119e00 64a135c8 00000000 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd2c 00000000 00000000
> 61aadd6c 6104cf08   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd3c 6195ee5c 00000000 625b3aa7 619b0000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd4c be931734 4011c2ec 634ab1b3 61aadd6c
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd5c 6195ee5c
> 61aadd6c 634ab1db 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadd6c 00000000 6195ee28 6195ee30 61aadd84   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadd7c 625b5b8b 625b3aa7
> 5fe10a48 0000001b   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadd8c 6abfd550 687ab860 640e7af8 6195ee28   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> memory near sp: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadb90 648fce10 648fbae4 648fbae0 648fce18   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadba0 648fbae4 400e13a7 648fbad0 00000000
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbb0 61aadbf4
> 00000003 61aadc16 61aadc14   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadbc0 61aadc04 62a21d67 6465d730 648fba88   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbd0 619292f8 400e13a7
> 61aadc14 61aadc04   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadbe0 61aadc0c 6465d730 61aadc14 62a17a75   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadbf0 61aadc04 61aadc16 641ff368 62589eab
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc00 64957ec0
> 00000000 6256bcad 638ddd60   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc10 00000003 00610006 00700070 00000000   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc20 6271d62b 6104cf08
> 639f5b1c 634a88a1   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc30 65ed8fa8 619292f8 61aadd10 634aa101   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc40 0000411a 00000000 00000003 6394bcd8
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc50 61aadcc4
> be931734 61aadc78 400ddca9   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     61aadc60 00000000 63555278 61aadccc 6104d0d4   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     61aadc70 65ece858 64905740
> 00000021 625efad9   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 61aadc80 0000001c 00000001 65ece858 00000000   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   : code
> around pc: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a219e8
> 1f00e852 0e00e842 0f00f1be f3bfd1f8   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I
> DEBUG   :     62a219f8 b1218f5f 2078f8d8 d1fb2a00 681ae7ee   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a08 b1316811 ba1b680b
> 89936013 81933301   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 62a21a18 4640e004 f7f84632 4601fc5b f1012200   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a28 f3bf030c f8c88f5f 603b2078 e8812301
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a38 688b0028
> 0317f362 0e1b608b 03fef003   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     62a21a48 0302f043 0382f362 602172cb e8bd4620   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a58 bf0081f0 00fd025a
> 00fd024c 41f0e92d   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 62a21a68 46174606 b939460d f0016039 4601fdd9   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a78 f7fc4630 e061fde1 42994b32 deffd900
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a88 004c4b31
> 681b447b 340c781b f7f9b90b   12-29 13:33:23.324   878   878 E
> QualCommAdapter: ISS v4lInitMmap Success 12-29 13:33:23.324   167
> 167 I DEBUG   :     62a21a98 482ef8fb f384fab4 68004478 0120f1c3
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21aa8 0381eb00
> 46806fdb f203fa24 0340f101   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     62a21ab8 3023f850 0207f002 2b004023 4613bf0c   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     62a21ac8 eb031c53 eb0003c1
> 20010383 3184f8d3   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 62a21ad8 0278f108 1f00e852 0e00e842 0f00f1be   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   : code
> around lr: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000000
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I
> DEBUG   :     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000050 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     000000a0 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29
> 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324
> 167   167 I DEBUG   :     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
> 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     000000f0 ffffffff
> ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff   12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG
> :  12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   : memory map around fault
> addr 2bc01020: 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     (no map
> below) 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :     (no map for
> address) 12-29 13:33:23.324   167   167 I DEBUG   :
> 333f9000-333fa000 r-x  12-29 13:33:23.354   878   878 E Scanner :
> productparams xml doesn't exist 12-29 13:33:23.354   878   878 E
> libimgkit: DecParamSet failed to set 0x16b to 0x0. Error 11 12-29
> 13:33:23.364   878   878 E SPB     : Marking invalid param
> decoder_uspostnet_report_check_digit 12-29 13:33:23.364   878   878 E
> SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> decoder_uspostnet_report_check_digit 12-29 13:33:23.364   878   878 E
> SPB     : Marking invalid param decoder_usplanet_report_check_digit
> 12-29 13:33:23.364   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : decoder_usplanet_report_check_digit 12-29 13:33:23.364   878
> 878 E SPB     : Marking invalid param decoder_webcode 12-29
> 13:33:23.364   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : decoder_webcode 12-29 13:33:23.364   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param decoder_webcode_subtype 12-29 13:33:23.364   878
> 878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> decoder_webcode_subtype 12-29 13:33:23.364   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param bt_disconnect_on_exit 12-29 13:33:23.364   878
> 878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> bt_disconnect_on_exit 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param connection_idle_time 12-29 13:33:23.374   878
> 878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> connection_idle_time 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param display_bt_address_barcode 12-29 13:33:23.374
> 878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> display_bt_address_barcode 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param establish_connection_time 12-29 13:33:23.374
> 878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> establish_connection_time 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param power_mode 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB
> :  Not adding since param is invalid : power_mode 12-29 13:33:23.374
> 878   878 E SPB     : Marking invalid param viewfinder_feedback_mode
> 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : viewfinder_feedback_mode 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E
> SPB     : Marking invalid param viewfinder_feedback_time 12-29
> 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : viewfinder_feedback_time 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E
> SPB     : Marking invalid param viewfinder_mode 12-29 13:33:23.374
> 878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid :
> viewfinder_mode 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     : Marking
> invalid param Adaptive_Scanning 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB
> :  Not adding since param is invalid : Adaptive_Scanning 12-29
> 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     : Marking invalid param Beam_Width
> 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : Beam_Width 12-29 13:33:23.374   878   878 E SPB     :
> Marking invalid param decoder_signature 12-29 13:33:23.384   878   878
> E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid : decoder_signature
> 12-29 13:33:23.384   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : Adaptive_Scanning 12-29 13:33:23.394   878   878 E SPB     :
> Not adding since param is invalid : Beam_Width 12-29 13:33:23.394
> 878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid : power_mode
> 12-29 13:33:23.414   878   878 E SPB     : Adding Hidden param to map
> Imager Mode id imager_mode 12-29 13:33:23.414   878   878 E SPB     :
> Not adding since param is already in the main map : aim_mode 12-29
> 13:33:23.414   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> already in the main map : aim_type 12-29 13:33:23.424   878   878 E
> SPB     :  Not adding since param is already in the main map :
> illumination_mode 12-29 13:33:23.474   878   878 E SPB     :  Not
> adding since param is invalid : decoder_uspostnet_report_check_digit
> 12-29 13:33:23.474   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : decoder_usplanet_report_check_digit 12-29 13:33:23.504   878
> 878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is invalid : decoder_signature
> 12-29 13:33:23.514   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : viewfinder_mode 12-29 13:33:23.514   878   878 E SPB     :
> Not adding since param is invalid : bt_disconnect_on_exit 12-29
> 13:33:23.514   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : connection_idle_time 12-29 13:33:23.514   878   878 E SPB
> :  Not adding since param is invalid : establish_connection_time 12-29
> 13:33:23.514   878   878 E SPB     :  Not adding since param is
> invalid : display_bt_address_barcode 12-29 13:33:23.524   878   878 E
> SPB     : Adding Hidden param to map Hardware Trigger IDs id
> hw_trigger_ids 12-29 13:33:23.574   878   878 D AAA     :
> HWTriggerCallback>isValidateUser :true

Any idea about why this case is not reported by the crashlytics plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's a native c++ crash. Crashlytics supports native crashes using the Crashlytics NDK SDK. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to enable the native crashes on my app but is not working, my app is not a native, is a cordova project, is it ok?

Comment: Crashlytics doesn't officially support Cordova projects so enabling NDK crash reporting isn't something we've tested out.